# where is the "Add widgets" icon on API 8

Tags: android

My android app has a widget that works fine on API 11 and above. Since i used the Appcompat support libraries, i expect it to work on API 8 as well. So I tried it on an AVD with API 8, but i could not find the widget option on the homescreen.

On API 11, there was a `+` icon which showed the available widgets from where i could choose mine. But i cannot find any such icon on the AVD with API 8. So where exactly is it?

**appwidget-provider xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="40dp"
    android:minHeight="40dp" 
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/ic_widget_on"

    >

</appwidget-provider>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long press on the Home screen to see the Widgets option on API < 11.